# User agent of BingWeb - bot or mobile agent?

Tags: bing, user-agent, bingbot

When I scan my logs for user agents containing `Bing` (capitalized), I find two types of user agents: those containing `BingPreview` and those containing `BingWeb`.

Bing [lists](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0) `BingPreview` as one of their bots, but I can't find anything on `BingWeb`. It doesn't show up on the traditional sites that parse/identify user agents like [this one](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/bingpreview/) nor on the same [site's list of bot software](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/).

All the user agents seem to be Android. I'm wondering if perhaps this is a mobile browser of sorts? Some example user agents:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-N950U Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.7.26217602`

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G960U Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/66.0.3359.158 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.5.26198602`

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; LM-X210(G) Build/N2G47H; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.6.26207901`

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LGMP450 Build/NRD90U; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.7.26217602`

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Z958 Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.7.26217602`

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Moto Z (2) Build/ODXS27.109-34-12; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36 BingWeb/8.7.26217602`